# Issue of greater than value entered by user using jquery

Tags: jquery

[image]

When user enter a consume quantity is greater than stock quantity then show the error msg otherwise not showing the error msg.

In image show that 3 is less than from 15 so its still showing a error msg, it is wrong that.

If user entered 11 in consume qty field then error msg is not show

**Issue:** If user enter a digit to 2 from 9 then error msg is show

```
<input id="stock_qty" type="text" name="stock_qty" value="15" style="display:none;">
<input id="consume_qty" type="text" name="consume_qty">
<span id="error" style="display: none;font-size: 12px;color: red;">Quantity has been increased.</span>

<script>
  $("#consume_qty").on('change', function() {
  if ($('#consume_qty').val() > $('#stock_qty').val()) {
            $('#error').show();
        } 
  else{
    $('#error').hide();
   }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: run the comparison on an event bind it to the consume. Could be on change,on keypress,on blur,on input pick what is best for you scenario

Comment: I updated my code check it please

Comment: @Hayamkhan And doesn't it work?

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do this check on `.change()` handler and convert the values to numbers with `parseFloat()`.

```
$('#consume_qty').change(function () {  
    var stock = parseFloat($('#stock_qty').val());
    var consume = parseFloat(this.value);

    $('#error').toggle(consume > stock);
});
```

Or better yet, use jQuery validation plugin and refer to [this post](/a/29451695/3634538) for creating custom validation method.

Comment: this answer is the same as the OP. No explanation was given

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be ok but you need to trigger the change event by doing blur or focus on the input. Use on input event if you want to check during typing on the input

```js
$("#consume_qty").on('input', function() {
  if ($('#consume_qty').val() > $('#stock_qty').val()) {
    $('#error').show();
  } else {
    $('#error').hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="stock_qty" type="text" name="stock_qty" value="15" style="display:none;">
<input id="consume_qty" type="text" name="consume_qty">
<span id="error" style="display: none;font-size: 12px;color: red;">Quantity has been increased.</span>
```